# Search Ajax return data for item with dropdownlist field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am populating a dropdownlist with 'description' values that I retrieve from an MVC controller action, which is working great. The return objects actually have many more fields on them, and I am trying to set form fields to these values when the dropdown list is picked.

I need to search the returned data for an object with the corresponding ID, but can't find out how;

My ajax success section is below. I am trying to achieve this in ddl.change();

```
            success: function(data) {
            if (!data) {
                // oops
                return;
            }
            ddl.empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $(document.createElement('option'))
                    .attr('value', item.Id)
                    .text(item.Description)
                    .appendTo(ddl);
            });


            // something like this //
            /////////////////////////
            ddl.change(function() {
                $("Address1").val(data.find($(this).val()).Address1);
            });
        },
```

I hope this makes sense. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a library called lodash for this sort of thing. You presumably have a list that's returned from your AJAX call. And you have an ID that is selected from the dropdown. You can use the find method in lodash to search your list for you ID, and return the data that you need.

https://lodash.com/docs#find

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I wanted and works great. Thanks!